# Pre-Built Module bind

Tags: pact-lang

I am new with Pact (Kadena.io), Could you please give me an easy explanation about what the module bind does ? the explanation in the manual is not completely clear to understand.

Thank you.

## pact-lang

Answer (score 2):

The `bind` function takes a row object as an input and allows you to associate variable names with the values associated with the keys of that object. For example, suppose I have the following object:

```
{ "foo" : "is"
, "bar" : 1
, "baz" : 3
}
```

When I call `bind` on this object, I can associate the values in of the object with a variable name that I specify and subsequently use those variables in expressions within the binding scope. Consider the following example:

```
(let ((obj { "foo": "is", "bar": 1, "baz": 3 }))
  (bind obj 
    { "foo" := foo
    , "bar" := bar
    , "baz" := baz
    }
    (format "1 + 3 {} {}" [foo (+ bar baz)]))
  )
```

This will output the string "1 + 3 is 4", by binding our own variable name definitions and using them in a formatting expression that returns a string. Notice what we've done here though. We've taken the values associated with the keys of the object `obj`, and *bound* them to a variable name, which we can work with in the scope of the binding function. This allows us to work with objects in a robust way. It even supports partial bindings on just parts of the object!

So the key takeaway here for the `bind` function is this:

- When you work with objects, `bind` allows you to work with the values in the object as variable names.
- The symbol `:=` is this symbol that allows you to bind a key to a variable name. You may encounter this symbol with other functions, such as `with-read` and `resume`, and it always refers to the act of binding a value to some name.
- You may use the variables for whatever purpose as long as they do not escape the binding scope.

I hope that clears things up.